# library not found for -lTestFlight when building Cordova project with Testflight plugin installed via plugman

Tags: ios, cordova, testflight

I used a `plugman` command to install the TestFlight plugin for my ios Cordova project. The TestFlight plugin is found at https://github.com/shazron/TestFlightPlugin. The plugman install command id below.

`plugman --install --platform ios --project ./TestFlightApp --plugin https://github.com/shazron/TestFlightPlugin`

I receive the following when attempting to run the project on my device

```
ld: library not found for -lTestFlight
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Ive been digging and it seems that the changes to `project.pbxproj` are the ones causing the build fail.

Are there any known issues or known resolutions to installing via `plugman`? I am glad to provide more context if that would help too, just let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`plugman 0.7.7` was just pushed that fixes this issue :)

Original issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-3431

The issue was being fixed as I reported it to the plugin maintainers: https://github.com/shazron/TestFlightPlugin/issues/9